# How do you Identify the interface of a packet while listening to network traffic on all devices?

Tags: python, pcap, libpcap, tcpdump, scapy

I am writing a python program that needs to listening to traffic on all networking devices and identify packets based on their incoming interface.  To listen on all interfaces I started my capture without specify a device, but I am unable to denote the interface of a particular packet.  How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the MAC address is sufficient information for you.

> The first 6 octets of a packet is the destination MAC address, which is immediately followed by the 6 octets of source MAC address.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014218/python-and-libpcap-find-source-mac-address-of-packet)

[image: 802.3 Ethernet frame structure]

Comment: using the code from the post below I can determine the MAC to device name; are you aware of another way that will be able to determine this information without being run on the capturing machine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address