# Python - Scapy Choosing an interface to sniff

Tags: python, scapy, sniffer

Im building a sniffer with Scapy, python 2.6.6 and windows 7 and I want to know if I can choose the interface to sniff before sniffing, kind of like Wireshark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *iface* parameter.

```
sniff(iface="wlan0", prn=exampleFunction)
```

But if no interface is given, sniffing will happen on every interfaces.

You can look in the Sniffing section in the [Scapy webpage](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html)

Comment: Can you provide a source for the "sniffing will happen on every interface" statement?

Comment: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html In the Sniffing section "We can easily capture some packets or even clone tcpdump or tethereal. If no interface is given, sniffing will happen on every interfaces"

Comment: if no interface is given, it'll look at all of them, but then if it does, is there a way to see which interface sniffed the packet?

Comment: @JohnSly you could [map the MAC address to the interface name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845719/how-do-you-identify-the-interface-of-a-packet-while-listening-to-network-traffic).

Comment: This is coming 7 years later but it's worth noting that not specifying `iface` will *not* capture from all interfaces, it will capture from the default one specified by `conf.iface`.

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is a dated post.  One of the solutions mentions:

> But if no interface is given, sniffing will happen on every interfaces.
>   You can look in the Sniffing section in the Scapy webpage

Unfortunately the documentation is wrong.  When no interface is given then the scapy sniffs on *conf.iface*

Please see the conversation on their github repo:

> https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1356

Comment: I ended up creating a thread for each interface and calling sniff() separately then queueing the packets...